# uploading photos to facebook album from a url sent via http post from another website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

im working on a website that lets users view photos.. i wanted them to be able to press on the photo and the photo gets sent staight to their facebook account... so far ive found this documentation that allows users to upload photos from local mashine [How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/).. is there an way of modifying this code so it recieves a url from a http post from another website?

```
   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $post_login_url = "YOUR_POST-LOGIN_URL";
   $album_name = 'YOUR_ALBUM_NAME';
   $album_description = 'YOUR_ALBUM_DESCRIPTION';

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code))
     {
       $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
       echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
       "'</script>");
   } 
   else {
     $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
     . "access_token?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];

     // Create a new album
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
     . "access_token=". $access_token;

     $postdata = http_build_query(
     array(
      'name' => $album_name,
      'message' => $album_description
        )
      );
     $opts = array('http' =>
     array(
      'method'=> 'POST',
      'header'=>
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $postdata
      )
     );
     $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
     $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
       $context));

     // Get the new album ID
     $album_id = $result->id;

     //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
       . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
     echo '<html><body>';
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
     .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
     echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
     echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
     echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
     echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
     echo '<input name="message" type="text"
        value=""><br/><br/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</body></html>';
  }
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/:

> You can also publish a photo by providing a `url` param with the photo's URL.

That’s all you have to do – [post to `/PROFILE_ID/photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos), and replace the `source` parameter with one called `url`, containing the address of the photo where it is publicly reachable via HTTP.